# ubuntu 18.04 not booting anymore after installing nvidia

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

I tried to install nvidia, the installation froze and since I cannot reboot. I have booted from a usb drive and tried boot-repair, it gave me this error report:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/J6xPTj6G8M/

Very thankful if anyone has an idea!

Comment: With Secure boot on, you have to provide your own UEFI Secure Boot key to authorize the install of third party (nVidia) drivers. Ubuntu cannot certify someone else's blob of code, but you can if you know it is ok. Most just turn off UEFI Secure Boot, so nVidia driver installs. But make sure you purge an old driver, before installing a new one, if you do have one already installed. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot

Comment: It starts to boot, then it says 'Stopping user manager for UID 121...' on a black screen (the other messages are fine) and this screen is flickering forever. I saw others had this because their hard drive s full but mine is not (I checked with gparted from  USB drive)

Comment: if you do not have nVidia driver installed, you need nomodeset boot parameter (replace quiet splash on linux line) or recovery mode which has nomodeset as default. If only Ubuntu and UEFI, you have to press Escape key right after vendor's logo & before grub. May take a couple of tries. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it